# Why is "Not Modified" a redirection ("3xx") status code?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

If you do a `GET` request for a resource then it makes very much sense that you can get a *Not Modified* response to avoid unnecessary traffic.

The question is why the return code is `304`? This means it is a *redirection* response. What would be the expected redirection location in such a scenario?

I would have expected that it is something within the `2xx` range as it was a *successful* request with a valid answer.

See the [RFC](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please don't use the old and long outdated RFC 2616 as reference anymore.** It was completely obsoleted by the RFCs 7230-35, which together define the HTTP protocol.

---

As stated in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), there are several types of redirects and one of them is *an implicit redirection to a cached resource*, as indicated by the [`304`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1) status code (highlight is mine):

> [**6.4.  Redirection 3xx**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4)
>
> The `3xx` (Redirection) class of status code indicates that **further
> action needs to be taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the
> request.** [...]
>
> There are several types of redirects:
>
> 1. Redirects that indicate the resource might be available at a
>    different URI, as provided by the `Location` field, as in the
>    status codes `301` (Moved Permanently), `302` (Found), and `307`
>    (Temporary Redirect).
> 2. Redirection that offers a choice of matching resources, each
>    capable of representing the original request target, as in the
>    `300` (Multiple Choices) status code.
> 3. Redirection to a different resource, identified by the `Location`
>    field, that can represent an indirect response to the request, as
>    in the `303` (See Other) status code.
> 4. **Redirection to a previously cached result, as in the `304` (Not
>    Modified) status code.**

See below how the [`304`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1) status code is defined in the [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232):

> [**4.1.  304 Not Modified**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-4.1)
>
> The `304` (Not Modified) status code indicates that a conditional `GET`
> or `HEAD` request has been received and would have resulted in a `200`
> (OK) response if it were not for the fact that the condition
> evaluated to false.  In other words, there is no need for the server
> to transfer a representation of the target resource because the
> request indicates that the client, which made the request
> conditional, already has a valid representation; the server is
> therefore redirecting the client to make use of that stored
> representation as if it were the payload of a `200` (OK) response.

Answer (score 1):

It is redirecting to the copy of the data stored in the cache.